# Sympy, Matrices of general size, derivatives

Tags: sympy

I'm not sure if the following is possible. I tried looking at the docs, but see a lot of physics stuff and not quite what I want.

Is it possible to be like matrixcalculus.org, and specify say a general matrix Q of shape (m,n), x, a vector of shape n, and do this kind of calculation. Rather than limiting it to a set number of dimensions and specifying each element individually [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MatrixSymbol`:

```
In [5]: n = Symbol('n')

In [6]: Q = MatrixSymbol('Q', n, n)

In [7]: x = MatrixSymbol('x', n, 1)

In [8]: f = x.T @ Q @ x

In [9]: f
Out[9]: 
 T    
x ⋅Q⋅x

In [10]: diff(f, x)
Out[10]: 
       T  
Q⋅x + Q ⋅x
```

If you substitute a concrete value for `n` then `as_explicit` can give you the expanded result:

```
In [11]: diff(f, x).subs(n, 2).as_explicit()
Out[11]: 
⎡2⋅Q₀₀⋅x₀₀ + Q₀₁⋅x₁₀ + Q₁₀⋅x₁₀⎤
⎢                             ⎥
⎣Q₀₁⋅x₀₀ + Q₁₀⋅x₀₀ + 2⋅Q₁₁⋅x₁₀⎦
```

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html

Comment: Thanks. That's incredible, and exactly the functionality i was looking for

Comment: I wonder if you know if its possible to do this but with a function that is a sum of vectors. This would be so useful to me, I tried with index based. eg. like taking derivative of this $$f\left(\boldsymbol{x}\right)= \sum_{k=1}^{10}\left\|\boldsymbol{x}\right\|_{2}^{2}$$

Comment: Sorry @oscarbenjamin, I can't get it to render. Like this https://ibb.co/XFJjZWM?

Comment: I tried this without success. I get the error message 'MatrixSymbol' object has no attribute '_diff_wrt'. Any ideas about the possible issues?

Comment: Try a newer version of SymPy. I just tested and confirmed that this works with the latest version (1.8)

Comment: @JimSi you can probably use `Sum` and some combination of things in the matrix expressions module.